# what is the command for listing files/dirs recursively of specific directories

Tags: linux, solaris, ls, directory-listing

suppose in my current directory, I have 50 sub-directories. Now, I am interested only in about 20 of those sub-directories (whose names match a pattern). I would like to recursively list the contents of these 20 sub-directories. How do I do that ?

I would like to do this in Solaris 10 and Linux(RHEL 5.x).

thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Use tree. Just navigate to the directory you want to get the structure for, and type tree.
For more see [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/tree.htm). Use the -l and -r switches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ls` and `find` to accomplish this. Simply use `find` to get the directories and pass those into `ls`:

```
ls `find -type d -name my_dir`
```

If you need more verbose output, you can also use `ls`'s options:

```
ls `find -type d -name my_dir` -al
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, Solaris is a BSD variant, so `find` will need the `-print` option.

Comment: You are probably correct. I haven't used Solaris in a long time.

Answer (score 0):

ls -R *pattern*, if you can express pattern as a shell glob.